# How do I get Java to use my Security provider?

Tags: java, security

I wrote a custom security provider for AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding. That works fine.

What settings do I need to add to the `Provider` in order for Java to recognize it as a valid provider for the above algorithm? I already have

```
public class FooBarProvider extends Provider {
  public FooBarProvider() {
    super("FooBar", 1.0, "Provider for AES.");
    put("Cipher.AES", "foo.bar.AESCipher");
  }
}
```

where the latter argument is the actual `CipherSpi` that does the work. Where do I register the fact that it supports CBC and PKCS5Padding? Currently asking for a relevant `Cipher` does not return an instance of my class:

```
Security.insertProviderAt(new FooBarProvider(), 1);
Cipher cip = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
System.out.println(cip.getProvider()); //prints "SunJCE version 1.7"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Writing the code is the very simplest part of the process. You have already declared that your classes provide a Cipher implementation for AES. This line:

```
put("Cipher.AES", "foo.bar.AESCipher");
```

is pretty much all you need to accomplish the task. Also note that your implementation will automatically be called for all combinations of *mode* and *padding*, since you have registered your cipher implementation at the algorithm level.

Having said that, writing the code was the easy part. You are creating a cipher, so you will need to sign your JAR before it can be installed and configured as a provider. Because the process is somewhat involved I will not copy it all here, rather I will refer you to the [Oracle Guide on How to implement a Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html#Step4). It's an excellent source for this task.

If you follow the guide and still have issues, you may need to download and install the [JCE Unlimited Strength Policy](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html) appropriate to your installed JDK.

Comment: So I can't even install it to test its implementation?

Answer (score 8):

The Java Crypto documentation describes the mechanisms for registering a `Provider` class:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#Provider

The short version is:

1. Put the provider JAR on the classpath or in the Java installation's extensions directory.
2. Register the provider:

   - manually edit the details into the `java.security` config file (`$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/java.security`), or
   - at runtime, call `Security.addProvider` or `Security.insertProviderAt`.

Comment: I have that part (note the `insertProviderAt` call above), but what is the syntax for registering that my cipher supports CBC and PKCS5Padding?

Comment: "The short version ... " You say, it's not required to get the jars signed by a formal request to the runtime provider?

Answer (score 0):

`Provider`, `KeypairGenerator`, `KeyGenerator`, `KeyAgreement` and related service-spi-s may be integrated by subclassing and without registering the provider. For class `Cipher` there is no bypass inside the Java-Security framework and the steps from the accepted answer are mandatory. Nothing hinders you to provide public constructors for your cipher class and instantiate it without the framework.