# SecureRandom custom algorithm

Tags: java, random, secure-random

For testing purpose I need to use `SecureRandom` with a custom algorithm. How is it possible?

I think I have to subclass `SecureRandom` and provide a `SecureRandomSpi` custom implementation:

```
 167:   /**
 168:      A constructor for SecureRandom. It constructs a new 
 169:      SecureRandom using the specified SecureRandomSpi from
 170:      the specified security provier. 
 171: 
 172:      @param secureRandomSpi A SecureRandomSpi class
 173:      @param provider A Provider class
 174:    */
 175:   protected SecureRandom(SecureRandomSpi secureRandomSpi, Provider provider)
 176:   {
 177:     this(secureRandomSpi, provider, "unknown");
 178:   }
```

Is there a simple way or can anyone provide ad example?

Answer (score 0):

The constructor

```
protected SecureRandom(SecureRandomSpi secureRandomSpi, Provider provider)
```

is protected, you shouldn't use it. Use instead

```
public static SecureRandom getInstance(String algorithm)
```

If you have defined your own algorithm you must Create a Provider and register it so when you specify the name of the algorithm, the jre can find it. But you probably want to use a existig one.

However, if you have created your own crypto algorithm just use it instead of encapsulate into SecureRandom API. If its good enought sure some Provider will pay to you to add it to its API ;D

Comment: Can you write a simple example?

Comment: About using a existing alg? For example SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG"); sr.nextInt() will return a random integer from the 2^32 different values. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27622625/securerandom-with-nativeprng-vs-sha1prng. About register your own Provider I'm afraid there isn't such thing as a simple example. But look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060261/how-do-i-get-java-to-use-my-security-provider

Comment: About providing a custom alg. A simple one that return ++seed

Comment: What do you mean with "one that return ++seed"? You can use  SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG"); byte[] seed = sr.generateSeed(5); to obtain a 5 bytes seed computed using the SHA1PRNG seed generation algorithm . Do you need something like that?

Comment: I need to implement a custom algorithm. `SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("myCustomAlg");` For example myCustomAlg can simply return ++seed each `nextInt()`

Comment: Then you must create a security Provider, sign it and register it. As I said it's a complex process and there is no simple examples. You must follow the instructions from Oracle Docs. The point is, why do you want to use the SecureRandom API? This is an API designed to use well known cipher implementations. For testing purposes it will be simpler call to your own class. Something like MyCustomAlg.getRandomValue(seed);

Answer (score 0):

Late answer: **Yes** it is possible.

First I want to note, that I see a real usecase for having a custom random generator:

1. Providers of random generators have not had best press, e.g. [...paid RSA to make flawed crypto algorithm the default](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/12/report-nsa-paid-rsa-to-make-flawed-crypto-algorithm-the-default/). From this (story true of not true, intended or not) there should not be a blind trust decision in any provider. Flaws of single random generators may be elimintated by combining several generators from independent sources; e.g. *Random.org* might be conisdered as second source or a generator coming from an different algebraic class of pseudo random algorithms.
2. The regular procedure to integrate a random generator into a Java Runtime Environment is developping Provider + Algorithm class and getting it certified + system administration; a huge effort with additional constraints in context of *just* doing some testing.

Here is an example with a SecureRandom subclass.

```
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.SecureRandomSpi;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Combine several SecureRandom Generators
 * 
 * @author Sam Ginrich
 *
 */
public class CombinedRnd extends SecureRandom
{

    private static class CombiSpi extends SecureRandomSpi
    {

        CombiSpi(SecureRandom[] parts)
        {
            this.parts = parts;
        }

        @Override
        protected void engineSetSeed(byte[] seed)
        {
            parts[0].setSeed(seed);
        }

        @Override
        protected void engineNextBytes(byte[] bytes)
        {
            Arrays.fill(bytes, (byte) 0);
            int len = bytes.length;
            byte[] buf = new byte[len];
            for (SecureRandom r : parts)
            {
                r.nextBytes(buf);
                for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
                {
                    bytes[j] ^= buf[j];
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected byte[] engineGenerateSeed(int numBytes)
        {
            return null;
        }

        SecureRandom[] parts;

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -487720505474870937L;

    }

    public CombinedRnd(SecureRandom... parts)
    {
        super(createSPI(parts), null);
    }

    static SecureRandomSpi createSPI(SecureRandom[] parts)
    {
        return new CombiSpi(parts);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
    {
        SecureRandom[] sources = { SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG"), SecureRandom.getInstance("Windows-PRNG") };
        CombinedRnd secRnd = new CombinedRnd(sources);

        byte[] rndBytes = new byte[17];
        secRnd.nextBytes(rndBytes);

        for (byte r : rndBytes)
        {
            System.out.print(String.format("%02x ", r & 0xFF));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7550189683373026294L;

}
```