# how to load an external cryptographic provider dynamically

Tags: java, cryptography, hsm

how can i load a external hardware crypto provider dynamically while compiling/running a java program via cmd? is there any -providerclass switch like i have seen while using keytool?

Reference to any documentation will be appreciated.

Note: do not want to load provider statically via java.security file.

Comment: See [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10060400/5221149) of [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10060261/5221149), options 1 and 2B.

Comment: @Andreas Hello, i do not want to load provider from security file,is there a way i can provide at compile/run time using some switch?

Comment: **See second answer** of duplicate, **options** 1 and **2B**: *"at runtime, call `Security.addProvider` or `Security.insertProviderAt`"*